# Entity Linq consulta em relacionamento muitos-para-muitos

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

Herdei um banco que é intocável... Apesar de ter umas coisas muito "estranhas". Por exemplo tenho a seguinte situação que representaria um relacionamento n-n porém o relacionamento de fato não existe.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja um bairro pode ter muitos imóveis e um imóvel pode... ter muitos bairros. E pra piorar o relacionamento entre tbBairro e tbBairroImovel de fato não existe.

**Agora preciso buscar no banco uma lista com todos os imóveis que estão em uma lista de bairros.**
Tipo assim:

```
int[] ListaIdsBairros = { 10, 2, 37 };
imoveis = MeuContexot.tbImovel.Where(I => ListaIdsBairros.Contains(não sei o que por aqui));
```

Na verdade nem sei se é possível fazer essa pesquisa em uma unica linha.
Será que terei que fazer um looping em ListaIdsBairros adicionando o retorno de imoveis para cada bairro em uma lista geral de imoveis???

Alguém tem uma ideia de como fazer essa busca?

**Adicionado depois --------------------------------------------------**

Hoje apenas consigo fazer assim:

```
List<tbImovel> ResultImoveis = new List<tbImovel>();
        foreach (var Bairro in ListaDeIds)
        {
            List<tbImovel> Imoveis = new List<tbImovel>();
            Imoveis = ctx.tbBairroImovel.Where(bi => bi.idBairro == Bairro.idBairro).Select(bi => bi.tbImovel).ToList();
            foreach(var imovel in Imoveis)
            {
                ResultImoveis.Add(imovel);
            }
        }
```

Mas estou tentando melhorar isso.

Comment: O Lazy Loading esta habilitado? Essa "falha" no mapeamento tem cara de ter sido feito para evitar problema com a serialização dessa busca, mesmo estando errado.